# Python/Bash: comparing local and remote docker images sha256 hashes

Tags: python, bash, docker, docker-pull

The main goal: I have a very size-limited server and I can't afford docker pull of new image version while old layers are on server, so when new image is available, I remove the local one. But I don't want to do it when image wasn't updated as it takes several minutes to pull. I am trying to write a script that will compare remote and local sha256 hashes and act based on their difference.

**1st part of question**:

What I have in python:

```
import docker


def get_local_image_sha256(image_name):
    client = docker.from_env()
    image = client.images.get(image_name)
    return image.id


def get_remote_image_sha256(image_name):
    client = docker.from_env()

    try:
        manifest = client.images.get(image_name).attrs['RepoDigests'][0]
        # Extract SHA256 hash from the manifest
        sha256_hash = manifest.split('@')[1]
        return sha256_hash
    except docker.errors.ImageNotFound:
        print(f"Image '{image_name}' not found.")
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_name = "cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest"

    local_sha256 = get_local_image_sha256(image_name)
    remote_sha256 = get_remote_image_sha256(image_name)

    if local_sha256 and remote_sha256:
        print(f"Local Image SHA256: {local_sha256}")
        print(f"Remote Image SHA256: {remote_sha256}")
    else:
        print("Failed to obtain SHA256 hashes.")
```

It outputs:

```
Local Image SHA256: sha256:3995accefa763b49e743afb5a72a43be7cb0eb1acd14475f40496c002c6063d7
Remote Image SHA256: sha256:d80f38450a7ca2785afa9f18d790d7ff878dc8897dfab3af14e97983ab1e329e
```

Latest image is really ...9e in the cloud, but I don't know where ...d7 came from. When I use `docker pull cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest` just after script it outputs:

```
Pulling from crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server
Digest: sha256:d80f38450a7ca2785afa9f18d790d7ff878dc8897dfab3af14e97983ab1e329e
Status: Image is up to date for cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest
cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest
```

Why it says hashes are different in python but docker pull says image is latest?

**2nd part**:

Originally I tried in bash with script

```
LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW=$(docker manifest inspect cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest -v | jq -r .Descriptor.digest)
IMAGE_HASH_RAW=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest)
IMAGE_HASH_RAW="${IMAGE_HASH_RAW#*@}"

if [[ "$IMAGE_HASH_RAW" == "$LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW" ]]; then
  echo "$IMAGE_HASH_RAW is latest hash, skipping updating"
else
  echo "New hash is available, $LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW, reinstalling (old one is $IMAGE_HASH_RAW)"
fi
```

And it managed to output:

```
New hash is available, sha256:d80f38450a7ca2785afa9f18d790d7ff878dc8897dfab3af14e97983ab1e329e, old is sha256:d80f38450a7ca2785afa9f18d790d7ff878dc8897dfab3af14e97983ab1e329e, reinstalling
```

What's wrong with string comparation in bash? Script seemed to handle case when new image is available, but it doesn't do what I want when it's not...

**3rd part:**

In bash scipt I used `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest`, which outputs ...9e but there is another suggestion, `docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}' cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest`, which outputs ...d7. Why are they different and which one is correct for local latest hash?

Comment: One common piece of advice is to avoid reusing a tag like `latest` in your deployment pipeline; instead, give each build a unique tag, and update the deployment system with a new tag.  (This is especially true for Kubernetes.)  In this context, you'd just be able to do a simple string comparison if the image you're running is the same image as the one you want to deploy, without trying to decide whether to pull or not.  Would that approach work for you?

Comment: 1.  your python script is comparing two different types of hashes: the local image ID and the remote image digest. That's why they appear different even though the image is up to date.
2. the issue with the string comparison might be due to unexpected characters or whitespace in the hash values.
3. modify your Python script to compare the RepoDigests both locally and remotely.

Comment: Please focus this down to a single question. To ask another question, you would post a separate question to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment @Obaskly, it seems I figured out the situation.

1. As he mentioned, my python script was comparing two different types of hashes: the local image ID and the remote image digest, so it shouldn't be used for checking if image is up-to-date
2. Instead of comparing hashes in Bash, I wrote a python script with the most detailed debug possible and in Bash I compare using exit codes as string comparison doesn't work there as intended:

string_comparer.py:

```
import sys
import datetime
from itertools import zip_longest


def postprocess_string(s):
    return s.lower().strip()


def log_equal_strings(string1, string2):
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    log_message = f"{current_datetime}: {string1} is equal to {string2}\n"
    with open("comparison_log.txt", "a") as log_file:
        log_file.write(log_message)


def log_different_strings(string1, string2, position, char1, char2):
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    log_message = f"{current_datetime}: {string1} is not equal to {string2}, at position {position} first string has char {char1} ({ord(char1)}), second has char {char2} ({ord(char2)})\n"
    with open("comparison_log.txt", "a") as log_file:
        log_file.write(log_message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python compare_strings.py <string1> <string2>")
        sys.exit(1)

    string1 = postprocess_string(sys.argv[1])
    string2 = postprocess_string(sys.argv[2])

    if string1 == string2:
        print("Same!")
        log_equal_strings(string1, string2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Different!")
        for position, (char1, char2) in enumerate(zip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue=' '), start=1):
            if char1 != char2:
                log_different_strings(string1, string2, position, char1, char2)
                break
        sys.exit(1)
```

And Bash script turned into:

```
LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW=$(docker manifest inspect cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest -v | jq -r .Descriptor.digest)
IMAGE_HASH_RAW=$(docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest)
IMAGE_HASH_RAW="${IMAGE_HASH_RAW#*@}"

HASHES_EQUAL_RESULT=$(/usr/bin/python3 /home/pchela/string_comparer.py "$IMAGE_HASH_RAW" "$LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW")

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$IMAGE_HASH_RAW is latest hash, skipping updating"
else
  echo "Output of comparer is $HASHES_EQUAL_RESULT: new hash is available, $LATEST_IMAGE_HASH_RAW, reinstalling (old one is $IMAGE_HASH_RAW)"
fi
```

Seems now it works as intended.

3. `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' cr.yandex/crp110tk8f32a48oaeqo/ecr-server:latest` is what I wanted (local image digest).